# Error while adding location plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to add location plugin in my application but its throwing me an error.when i add some
other package its not giving the error.can someone help me in it.

Here's my pubspec.yaml code:

```
name: location
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+1
  location: ^2.3.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Error:

```
Error on line 27, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.


   ╷

27 │   location: ^2.3.5

   │   ^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

Comment: which sdk you are using? android studio or vs code?

Answer (score 1):

Is your project name by any chance by any chance the same name as your library name? 
Rename your project to something else than location, and it might work.